# error: installation of package ‘rgl’ had non-zero exit status

Tags: r, rgl

I would like to use plot 3D so I was trying to download rgl but whenever I am trying to install this,  I am getting this error in rgl package installation. So can you please suggest me something.

```
install.packages("rgl", dependencies=TRUE)
     Installing package into ‘/root/R/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-library/3.2’
     (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
     --- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
trying URL 'http://cran.skazkaforyou.com/src/contrib/rgl_0.95.1247.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2014799 bytes (1.9 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 1.9 MB

* installing *source* package ‘rgl’ ...
** package ‘rgl’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
checking for gcc... gcc -std=gnu99
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc -std=gnu99 accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc -std=gnu99 option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -std=gnu99 -E
checking for gcc... (cached) gcc -std=gnu99
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... (cached) yes
checking whether gcc -std=gnu99 accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking for gcc -std=gnu99 option to accept ISO C89... (cached) none needed
checking whether __attribute__((visibility())) is supported... yes
checking whether gcc -std=gnu99 accepts -fvisibility... yes
checking whether  accepts -fvisibility... no
checking for libpng-config... yes
configure: using libpng-config
configure: using libpng dynamic linkage
checking for X... libraries , headers 
checking GL/gl.h usability... no
checking GL/gl.h presence... no
checking for GL/gl.h... no
checking GL/glu.h usability... no
checking GL/glu.h presence... no
checking for GL/glu.h... no
configure: error: missing required header GL/gl.h
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rgl’
* removing ‘/root/R/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-library/3.2/rgl’

The downloaded source packages are in
‘/tmp/RtmpP1KuPN/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("rgl", dependencies = TRUE) :
      installation of package ‘rgl’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: See this line `checking GL/gl.h usability... no`. And have a look at [this page](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgl/index.html) which clearly states *SystemRequirements:  OpenGL, **GLU Library**, zlib (optional), libpng (>=1.2.9, optional), FreeType (optional)*
If I remember well, on Ubuntu, you need `libglu1-mesa-dev` and `mesa-common-dev`.

Answer (score 12):

The installation of `rgl` needs some system libraries to be previously installed. The [index page](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgl/index.html) of the package `rgl` provides some important information:

```
SystemRequirements: OpenGL, GLU Library, zlib (optional), libpng (>=1.2.9, optional), FreeType (optional)
```

Once we know that `OpenGL` and `GLU Library` are mandotory, we have to check whether they already are present or not in the system. One way is to read the log of the installation of `rgl`.
If these lines appear:

```
checking GL/gl.h usability... no
checking GL/gl.h presence... no
checking for GL/gl.h... no
checking GL/glu.h usability... no
checking GL/glu.h presence... no
checking for GL/glu.h... no
configure: error: missing required header GL/gl.h
```

It means that `GLU Library` is missing and must be installed.
For example, on Ubuntu, we can run:

```
sudo apt-get install libglu1-mesa-dev
```

In RedHat, it would be:

```
yum install Mesa-devel
```

This will install the headers of the `GLU Library`. And we can then run again:

```
install.packages("rgl", dependencies = TRUE)
```

Comment: In my case [Ubuntu 16.04] the problem was freetype (it seems it was not that optional), so I succeded after `sudo apt install libfreetype6-dev`