# R - can't install package "rgl"

Tags: r, x11, rgl

I've followed as many threads as I can on this to resolve, but no luck. Simply can't install R package "rgl". I have Upgraded Ubuntu server 16 to R version 3.3.1.

```
PuTTY X11 proxy: Unsupported authorisation protocol
Warning in rgl.init(initValue, onlyNULL) :
  RGL: unable to open X11 display
Warning: 'rgl_init' failed, running with rgl.useNULL = TRUE
* DONE (rgl)
```

I've tried these bits of advice:
[Error in installing rgl package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31820865/error-in-installing-rgl-package)
[error: installation of package ‘rgl’ had non-zero exit status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31982425/error-installation-of-package-rgl-had-non-zero-exit-status)

I have X11 working fine outside R:
http://www.tomsitpro.com/articles/how-to-use-x11-forwarding,2-843.html

but still get the error above.

Thanks for any help,

S.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, this seems to be solved. I was root, after exiting and using:
    sudo R

> install.packages("rgl")

everything was ok. so it seems you must install as sudo, not root, for everything to go in the right place.

Thanks,

S.

Answer (score 1):

I checked it. Everything seems to work properly... [Rscript - screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1ET9.png)

But in "related" here I see some questions about error in installing rgl. Take a look e.g. [Error in installing rgl package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31820865/error-in-installing-rgl-package?rq=1)